# C# - How to find and return distinguishedName value of OrganizationalUnit when I only have GUID to search by?

Tags: c#

Lets say all the information I have about an OrganizationalUnit is the objectGUID in hexadecimal format. This is the value: \6c\c4\35\1a\5e\bc\bf\8e\96\64\23\6c\30\3f\21\18

I'm able to use a directorySearcher and find it in Active Directory with a FindOne() and using a .Filter (objectGUID=(hexvalue)), but I'm not able to return the distinguishedName. With C# I want to use that GUID value to search for it in Active Directory using System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry or similar, and then return the distinguishedName value of the orgUnit.

How would I go about doing that? Of course I also have the domain in which the orgUnit exists.

```
public static string GetDNviaGUID(string queryGuid)  
{  
    using(System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry de = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://XXXX.Local/<GUID=" + queryGuid + ">"))
    {
        return de.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value.ToString();
    }  
}
```

I'm trying this but getting errors.
The error I'm getting is:
(0x80072032): An invalid dn syntax has been specified.

Comment: What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: @RoninEngineer I edited the original post to include the error at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was actually able to do it in the end but I had to write a lot more code than i thought. This is the original code I talked about where I said I was able to search for it and find it using FindOne(), but I wrote some more code with a GetDirectoryEntry() so I could also get the distinguishedName like I wanted to.
Would love some feedback on how to make it simpler.

```
public static string GroupFunction(string guid)
{
    using (System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher searcher = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher())
        {
            var guidToSearch = ConvertToSearchableGUID(guid); 
            //return "\\" + guidToSearch;

            //searcher.Filter = $"(objectGuid=\\3b\\c6\\35\\2b\\8e\\bc\\bf\\4b\\95\\34\\17\\6d\\31\\3d\\22\\17)";

            searcher.Filter = $"(objectGuid={guidToSearch})";
            
            searcher.SearchRoot = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://XXXX");
            var SearchResult = searcher.FindOne();
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
            if(SearchResult == null)
            {
                return "False";
            }

            if(SearchResult != null)
            {
                System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ou = SearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
                string distinguishedName = ou.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value.ToString();
                return distinguishedName;
            }
        }
        return "";
}
```